# From where the lyrics is taken for the following song? Shri Radhe Sharanam Mamah

Tags: identification-request, stotra, radha

The song found on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/AbR83RmrKHs) sung by Pt. Jasraj ji

Full lyrics

Lyrics for Shri Radhe Sharanam Mamah by Pandit Jasraj
shree radhey sharnam mamah

> chaturmukhadi sanstutam
>   samasta satwatanutam
>   halayudadi samyutam
>   namami radhikadhipam
>
> bakadi daitya kalkam
>   sagop gopi palakam
>   manoharasi thalkam
>   namami radhikadhipam
>
> surendra garva bhanjanam
>   viranchi moh bhanjanam
>   brajanjananuranjanam
>   namami radhikadhipam
>
> mayurprichha mandanam
>   gajendra dant khandanam
>   nrishinsha kansa dandanam
>   namami radhikadhipam
>
> pradatta vipradarakam
>   sudama dham karakam
>   suradrumapaharakam
>   namami radhikadhipam
>
> dhanjaya jayapaham
>   maha cha mookshayavaham
>   pitamahavyathapaham
>   namami radhikadhipam

Comment: [Radha Krishna Ashtakam](http://www.celextel.org/stotras/vishnu/radhakrishnashtakam.html)

Answer (score 6):

It is Krishnashtakam by Brahmananda.

You can read it in Sanskrit at [Sanskrit Documents](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/brahmaanandakrishna8.html?lang=sa) and English translation from [Vedanta Spiritual Library](http://www.shastras.com/vishnu-stotras/radha-krishna-ashtakam/).

> **॥ श्रीकृष्णाष्टक ब्रह्मानन्दविरचितं ॥**
>
> श्री गणेशाय नमः ।
>   चतुर्मुखादिसंस्तुतं समस्तसात्वतानुतम् ।
>   हलायुधादिसंयुतं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ १॥
>
> Chathur mukhadhi samsthutham, samastha sthvathonutham,
>   Halaudhadhi sayutham, namami radhikadhipam. 1
>
> I salute the Lord of Radha,
>   Who is worshipped by Brahma and other devas,
>   Who is always worshipped by good people,
>   And who is accompanied by Bala Rama and others.
>
> बकादिदैत्यकालकं सगोपगोपिपालकम् ।
>   मनोहरासितालकं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ २॥
>
> Bhakadhi daithya kalakam, sagopagopipalakam,
>   Manoharasi thalakam, namami Radhikadhipam. 2
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who killed asuras like Baka,
>   Who looked after gopas and gopis,
>   And who had pretty black lock of hair.
>
> सुरेन्द्रगर्वगञ्जनं विरञ्चिमोहभञ्जनम् ।
>   व्रजाङ्गनानुरञ्जनं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ ३॥
>
> Surendra garva banjanam, virinchi moha banjanam,
>   Vrujanga nanu ranjanam, namami Radhikadhipam. 3
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who broke the pride of Devendra,
>   Who cured the illusion of Lord Brahma,
>   And who pacified the gopis.
>
> मयूरपिच्छमण्डनं गजेन्द्रदन्तखण्डनम् ।
>   नृशंसकंसदण्डनं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ ४॥
>
> Mayura pincha mandanam, gajendra danda gandanam,
>   Nrusamsa kamsa dandanam, namami Radhikadhipam. 4
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who decorates himself with feather of peacock,
>   Who broke the tusks of the elephant,
>   And who punished Kamsa.
>
> प्रदत्तविप्रदारकं सुदामधामकारकम् ।
>   सुरद्रुमापहारकं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ ५॥
>
> Pradatha vipradarakam, sudhamadhama karakam,
>   Suradrumapaharakam, namami Radhikadhipam. 5
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who gave back the children of the Brahmin,
>   Who removed poverty of Sudhama,
>   And who stole the tree from heaven.
>
> धनञ्जयाजयावहं महाचमूक्षयावहम् ।
>   पितामहव्यथापहं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ ६॥
>
> Dananjaya jayapaham, maha chamookshayavaham,
>   Pithamahavyadhapaham, namami Radhikadhipam. 6
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who removed the defeats of Arjuna,
>   Who destroyed huge army of enemies,
>   And who removed the sorrow to grand father Bheeshma.
>
> मुनीन्द्रशापकारणं यदुप्रजापहारणम् ।
>   धराभरावतारणं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ ७॥
>
> Muneendra sapa karanam, yaduprajapa harinam,
>   Dharabharavatharanam, namami Radhikadhipam. 7
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who was the cause of the curse of sages,
>   Which destroyed the people of Yadu clan,
>   And who lightened the load on the earth.
>
> सुवृक्षमूलशायिनं मृगारिमोक्षदायिनम् ।
>   स्वकीयधाममायिनं नमामि राधिकाधिपम् ॥ ८॥
>
> Suvruksha moola sayinam, mrugari mokshadhayinam,
>   Swakeeyadhamayayinam, namami Radhikadhipam. 8
>
> I salute the lord of Radha,
>   Who slept below a banyan tree,
>   Who gave salvation to hunters,
>   And who attained his place in heaven.
>
> इदं समाहितो हितं वराष्टकं सदा मुदा ।
>   जपञ्जनो जनुर्जरादितो द्रुतं प्रमुच्यते ॥ ९॥
>
> ॥ **इति श्रीपरमहंसब्रह्मानन्दविरचितं श्रीकृष्णाष्टकं सम्पूर्णम्** ॥

Comment: Transliteration please

Comment: @Sarvabhouma https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/brahmaanandakrishna8.itx

Comment: Who is Brahmananda?

Comment: @sv. I don't know, I think he may be [Swami Brahmananda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Brahmananda), direct discipline of Ramkrishna Paramhansa; but I'm not sure. You may ask the question. Btw, here is the list of Stotras written by the *same author*:- [Sanskrit Documents](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/brahmananda/), [Stotram](http://stotram.co.in/authors/paramahamsa-brahmananda/) may be useful for investigation.